# Flutter TextField in ListView hidden

Tags: flutter

I have a bottom sheet where I have a List View of Text Fields, unfortunately I haven't found a way to scroll up the List View until the Text Field is visible.

[image]

[image]

As I am tapping on the 10th Text Field, the Keyboard hides the Text Field.
Is there a way to scroll the item WITHIN the list view (not add insets to the whole list view) in such a way that it is not hidden?

Adding a Scaffold with "resizeToAvoidBottomInset" doesn't work in this case as it would scale the Bottom Sheet to the whole screen.

Thank you for your help!

Code sample:

```
import 'package:flutter/cupertino.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Flutter Demo',
        theme: ThemeData(
          primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
          brightness: Brightness.light,
        ),
        home: const TextFieldCovered()
        //  const MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
        );
  }
}

class TextFieldCovered extends StatelessWidget {
  const TextFieldCovered({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
      body: Center(
        child: CupertinoButton(
          child: const Text('Bottom Sheet'),
          onPressed: () => modalBottomSheet(context),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

void modalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) => showModalBottomSheet(
      context: context,
      builder: (context) => SizedBox(
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
        child: ListView.builder(
          itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
            color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.greenAccent,
            child: Row(
              children: [
                Expanded(
                  flex: 3,
                  child: Text(
                    index.toString(),
                    textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                  ),
                ),
                const Expanded(
                  child: CupertinoTextField(),
                ),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Set showModalBottomSheet `isScrollControlled` property to `true`
2. Wrap ListView.builder on `Padding` with padding property set to

   `EdgeInsets.only( bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom)`
3. Set Row `mainAxisSize` property to `MainAxisSize.min`

Now the `modalBottomSheet` should be look like this

```
void modalBottomSheet(BuildContext context) => showModalBottomSheet(
  context: context,
  isScrollControlled: true, //this
  builder: (context) => SizedBox(
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.6,
    child: Padding( //this
      padding: EdgeInsets.only(
          bottom: MediaQuery.of(context).viewInsets.bottom), //this
      child: ListView.builder(
        itemBuilder: (context, index) => Container(
          color: index % 2 == 0 ? Colors.amber : Colors.greenAccent,
          child: Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, //this
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text(
                  index.toString(),
                  textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                ),
              ),
              const Expanded(
                child: CupertinoTextField(),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

Comment: this works perfectly, could you explain why I need 
"mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min"?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: This gives constraint to the incoming layout.

Comment: Sorry to bother again, in my specific example (I forgot to include this in the minimal sample) I have:
Column(
children: [
Expanded(child: ListView.builder(... as seen in expample),
CupertinoButton(...),
],),

now the cupertino button slides up as well when the keyboard is opened, is there a way to let the keyboard cover this widget?

Comment: Not sure bro, but you can file another question here so everyone can see it. But to be honest I don't know what you are trying to accomplish on having to many text field on the bottom sheet.  Maybe you need to reconsider changing your approach, your UI. :)

Comment: My suggestion is, learn the use cases of the widgets. When to use it , and when not to use it. Good luck :)

Comment: It is for a gym app, you have multiple lines where you can add sets, and the text field is the weight of the set. And one can add as many sets as they want, therefor many textfields in a list view... :D